# User Pools for Amazon Cognito - CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create a Web App Authentication with help of [this](https://mobile.awsblog.com/blog/author/Ionut+Trestian) tutorial. Here is the code I have written -

```
var app = {};

app.configureCognito = function(){
    AWSCognito.config.region = 'us-east-1';

    var poolData = {
        UserPoolId: 'userPoolId',
        ClientId: 'ClientId'
    };

    var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var userData = {
                    UserName:'MyName',
                    Pool: userPool
    };

    var attributeList = [];

    var dataEmail = {
            Name: 'email',
            Value: 'mailme@mydomain.com'
    };

    var dataPhoneNumber = {
            Name: 'phone_number',
            Value: '+9112212212212'
    };

    var attributeEmail = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);
    var attributePhoneNumber = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataPhoneNumber);

    attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
    attributeList.push(attributePhoneNumber);

    var cognitoUser;

    userPool.signUp('userName','password',attributeList,null,function(err,result){
            if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    alert(err);
                    return;
            }
            cognitoUser = result.user;
            console.log('User Name is: '+cognitoUser);
    });

};
```

I am getting the error which says "missing credential in config", I understand that we are not doing any AWSCognito.config.credentials assignment here but isn't it supposed to use the information provided in userPool object? Is there anything wrong with the code any missing piece or something? As per the UserPoolId and client id are concerned both are 100% correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got it resolved by using below code apparently, there's no need to provide IdentityPoolId in this example at all, these are just the placeholders which can be left as below -

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: '...'
});

AWSCognito.config.region = 'us-east-1';
AWSCognito.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: '...' 
});
```

And both of the credential AWS.config.credentials and AWSCognito.config.credentials need to be set. Once the above steps complete the AWSCognito.config needs to be updated as below -

```
// Need to provide placeholder keys unless unauthorised user access is enabled for user pool
AWSCognito.config.update({accessKeyId: 'anything', secretAccessKey: 'anything'})

var poolData = { 
    UserPoolId : 'user pool id collected from user pool',
    ClientId : 'application client id of app subscribed to user pool'
};
```

dataPhoneNumber and userData are optional, dataPhoneNumber should be provided in case sms verification for signup is required.

The problem was resolved once the above were in place, [Identity-Code](https://github.com/jeetendra-choudhary/Identity-Code) is a working model if anyone want to have a look at it.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Also fixed my problem. This documentation is just horrible. Where did you find that information?

Comment: It was a tireless effort of hit and trial here is the complete code if you want to look for reference - https://github.com/jeetendra-choudhary/Identity-Code.git

Comment: @ReluMesaros Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

I used AWS amplify to configure AWS  sdk and AWS ses. I had the same error but was able to overcome using below solution. I used AWS amplify and React js.

Hope this helpful for who had issues with amplify and sdk.

```
Auth.currentCredentials().then(res => {

            AWS.config.update({
                region: 'ap-southeast-1',
                credentials: res
            });

            AWS.config.getCredentials(function (err) {
                if (err) console.log(err.stack); // credentials not loaded
                else console.log("Access Key:", AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId);
            })


            var ses = new AWS.SES({
                region: 'ap-south-1',
                apiVersion: '2010-12-01'
            });

            this.setState({
                open: false,
                ses: ses
            });

            AWS.config.getCredentials(function (err) {
                if (err) console.log(err.stack); // credentials not loaded
                else console.log("Access Key:", AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId);
            })

        })
```