# Integrating User Pools with Amazon Cognito Identity with authentication provider

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I follow the steps described in the link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html to integrate my user pool with cognito identity. But every time I am trying to access amazone S3 using the Authentication providers I get the following error:

> E/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Failure to get credentials
>                                                                                            com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException:
>   Logins don't match. Please include at least one valid login for this
>   identity or identity pool. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status
>   Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID:
>   ff4da8ad-9a96-11e6-9c64-67a5c841c727)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:712)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:388)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:199)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:558)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.getId(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:444)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.amazonaws.auth.AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.getIdentityId(AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.java:172)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.amazonaws.auth.AWSEnhancedCognitoIdentityProvider.refresh(AWSEnhancedCognitoIdentityProvider.java:76)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:561)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:371)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:441)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:76)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4369)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1704)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.uploadSinglePartAndWaitForCompletion(UploadTask.java:203)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:85)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:44)
>                                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
>                                                                                                 at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>                                                                                                 at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864).

Here is the code:

```
public static TransferUtility getTransferUtility(Context context) {
        if (sTransferUtility == null) {
            sTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(getS3Client(context.getApplicationContext()),
                    context.getApplicationContext());
        }

        return sTransferUtility;
    }



public static AmazonS3Client getS3Client(Context context) {
        if (sS3Client == null) {
            sS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(getCredProvider(context.getApplicationContext()));
        }
        return sS3Client;
    }



 private static CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider getCredProvider(Context context) {
        if (sCredProvider == null) {
            sCredProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    context.getApplicationContext(),
                    Constants.COGNITO_POOL_ID,
                    Regions.EU_WEST_1);
            Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<>();
            logins.put("cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/eu-west-1_xxxxxxxxx", idToken);
            sCredProvider.setLogins(logins);
        }
        return sCredProvider;
    }
```

Here how I get the token

```
AuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler = new AuthenticationHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CognitoUserSession cognitoUserSession, CognitoDevice device) {
            Log.e(TAG, "***Auth Success***");
            idToken = cognitoUserSession.getIdToken().getJWTToken();
            AppHelper.setCurrSession(cognitoUserSession);
            AppHelper.newDevice(device);
            closeWaitDialog();
            launchUser();
        }
```

The transferutility is part of com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility package.

Thank you for your help.
felini

Comment: This is no platform for free code-debugging.

Comment: Sorry I am not looking for debugging. I follow the steps described on amazone web site to integrate user pool to cognito identity. However I  always get failure to get credential. If someone can tell me why it will be great!

Comment: Problem solved!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User Pools for Amazon Cognito - CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259824/user-pools-for-amazon-cognito-credentialserror-missing-credentials-in-config)

Comment: Please have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259824/user-pools-for-amazon-cognito-credentialserror-missing-credentials-in-config

Comment: @Felini500 can you please update how you resolved this issue? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be configuration or the way you have created your token (the provider name part looks right). But most likely you just need to GetIdResult.

"Logins don't match. Please include at least one valid login for this identity or identity pool." is coming from the "AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetCredentialsForIdentity" api request (in java i think it is GetCredentialsForIdentityResult)

This can happen when you have an identityId for one identity, then you provide logins for another.  If you change identities you need to do a "AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetId" (in java i think this is GetIdResult)

The error is telling you that either it could not find the identity provider associated with the identity pool, or the pool does not have that identity provider configured (I think this generates a different error but not sure) , or it could not associate the identityId with the logins entry token (if the username claim in the ID token did not match the identity it had for instance).

I think you need to either fix your logins dictionary, or do a GetIdResult call to make sure you have the right identityId for the logins hash you are providing.

Or... if it is configuration, make sure that you have the user pool and client id properly configured in the Authentication Providers list as a Cognito user pool authentication provider.  Note that if you also configure it in IAM as an identity provider you must have the audience match that same client id.  (which also works).

Note:  This problem might happen if you configured "unauthenticated" access, then tried to get credentials with a logins hash, but using the unauthenticated identity.  I think you would need to do a getIdResult to switch.

Answer (score 1):

It was a configuration problem. I added to an existing identity pool, Cognito user pool as Authentication Providers. I provided the user pool Id and client Id.

Then I click save changes. It was shown in green on the dashboard that my changes was saved. But in reality it was not! That was the reason of the error.

As solution I created a new identity pool from scratch and added during the creation, cognito user pool as authentication provider. Only then it was properly saved after the pool creation.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has the same warning, it is possible to login to a Cognito Identity Pool with an **unverified email**, but that same user will not be able to authorise against a Cognito Identity Provider, instead this error will be thrown:

> Error: Logins don't match. Please include at least one valid login for
>   this identity or identity pool.

A user can be set to 'Confirmed' via the Cognito console. This does not equate to 'email verified'. The user CAN login to the pool though.

A fully unconfirmed user cannot login at all.