# message: 'Missing credentials in config', inside initiateAuth(), Which credentials am I missing?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to set up rudimentary functions for user authentication in my project, but when I ask for the auth token with aws-sdk function `initiateAuth()` it tells me that I'm missing credentials in my config object. I've managed to set up user creation and confirmation without any credentials. Whats more is that the documentation does not make it clear that `initiateAuth()` requires any credentials, or which credentials it wants.

When I ask for authentication, I get this error

```
{ Error: connect ENETUNREACH 169.254.169.254:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)
  message: 'Missing credentials in config',
  errno: 'ENETUNREACH',
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '169.254.169.254',
  port: 80,
  time: 2019-04-13T22:26:34.352Z,
  originalError:
   { message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
     errno: 'ENETUNREACH',
     code: 'CredentialsError',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '169.254.169.254',
     port: 80,
     time: 2019-04-13T22:26:34.352Z,
     originalError:
      { errno: 'ENETUNREACH',
        code: 'ENETUNREACH',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '169.254.169.254',
        port: 80,
        message: 'connect ENETUNREACH 169.254.169.254:80' } } }
```

my code is very simple

```
const http = require("http")
const aws = require('aws-sdk')
const JSON5 = require('json5')
const serviceProvider = aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider

aws.config.update({region : 'us-east-2'})
var service = new serviceProvider()


function authorizeUser(username, password){
    service.initiateAuth({
        AuthFlow: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH', 
        ClientId: 'placeholder', 
        AuthParameters: {
          'USERNAME': username,
          'PASSWORD': password
        },
    },
    function(error, data){
        if(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
        else if(data){
            console.log(data)
        }
    })

}
```

Why does this function seem to ask for credentials when it shouldn't need them? If it wants credentials, which ones does it need, and how do I provide them?

EDIT: This post solved my problem. I would still appreciate an answer as to why this works however.

all I did was change one line of code.

```
aws.config.update({region : 'us-east-2', accessKeyId: 'anything', secretAccessKey: 'anything'})
```

[User Pools for Amazon Cognito - CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259824/user-pools-for-amazon-cognito-credentialserror-missing-credentials-in-config)

Comment: Have you literally put 'anything' in both accessKeyId and secretAccessKey or have you put real access and secret keys of an IAM user?

Comment: I literally put 'anything' in the credentials. I have no idea why or how that allows it to work, but guessing is part of the magic of aws i suppose. The post I added in my edit sort of explains it. All they say is that if unauthorized access to the pool is disabled, you must provide placeholders in the credentials fields.

Comment: Then it seems to be an oversight on part of the developers of the sdk which validates config before doing anything else. It doesn't matter what you put in there as long as it isn't empty.

Comment: Indeed it would appear that way. Whats more is that the other post was asked in May of 2016. Meaning this has remained unchanged for almost 3 years.